# how can i add key value pair to the url which already existed key value pair in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have to click functions.In 1st click function i add the key value pair for existing url like this

```
$scope.OnItemClick=function (bedroom) {

    $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:bedroom});


}
```

so in remaining functions.I want to add extra key value pair based on existing url

```
  $scope.range=function (range) {
        $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({budget:range});
    }

    $scope.status=function (status) {
       $location.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({status:status});
   }
```

i tried to adding key value pair  but its over riding each other like this.

```
1st click : ../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1
2nd click :../#/builders/1?budget:5(overriding)
3rd click :../#/builders/1?status:9(overriding)
```

so i want to do like this based on clicking functions:

```
../#/builders/1?budget=5&bedrooms=1&status=9
../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1&status=9&budget=5
../#/builders/1?bedrooms=1&budget=5&status=9
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do like this and access them accordingly.

```
search({ "bedrooms" : "your_bedroom", "budget" : "your_range", "status" : "your_status"});
```

Comment: no your are setting at a time its generating in wrong way based on click functioncs i want to set

Comment: give some logic based on that i will access accordingly